# How to retrieve payment details from SESSION_ID by python stripe module?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'd like to retrieve payment details. When customer paid on stripe, redirect to my site with SESSION_ID. I can check the detail from the web site.

[image]

However I don't know how to call `POST /v1/payment_pages/` in python module.

I tried this code.

```
session_id = request.GET.get('session_id', None)
stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(session_id)
```

It returns this error:

`Request req_cv0slRS68E: No such payment_intent: 'cs_test_a1iUilPyU7NzO18T6xfQPabQZ4mOyoAPe93rtLEukggYXdmUjsskWxucWI'`

This method call `/v1/payment_intens/`.

[image]

How to retrieve payment details from `SESSION_ID`?
My session id format is `cs_test_a1iUilPyU7NzO18T6xf*****************`.

If you know how to use this session id to get the payment details, please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message and screenshot log, the function invoked was actually from `stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(..)` [0] instead of `stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(..)` [1]. PaymentIntent retrieval doesn't support Checkout Session ID (`cs_test_xxx`) and it only supports PaymentIntent ID (`pi_xxx`).

If `stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(..)` is used, its corresponding endpoint should be `GET /v1/checkout/sessions/cs_test_xxx` in the logs page. Please ensure that `stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(..)` is not used for Checkout Session retrieval.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve?lang=python 
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=python

Comment: I think my question was no good, I updated it. I'm using `stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve` then I got `No such payment_intent`. Please check my question again.Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to get payment intent details after a Checkout session is paid?

Comment: Yes, It is. Because when customer paid at stripe, then redirect to my site with session id. I want to know who paid and what plan bought.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround.

```
def get_payment_details(session_id, limit=10):
    sessions = stripe.checkout.Session.list(limit)
    for session in sessions:
        if session_id != session.id: continue
        return session
    return None
```

This method get recent sessions.Then if it is same session id, return the session ( payment details).